# MySQL won't replace words with empty space

Tags: mysql, replace

Basically, I have a problem with replace() function in MySQL (via phpMyAdmin). One table got messed and some special characters (+ empty space after it) appeared inside a word. So all I wanted to do was:

> UPDATE myTable SET columnName  =
>   (replace(columnName, 'Å house',
>   'house'))

But MySQL returns

```
0 row(s) affected. ( Query took 0.0107 sec )
```

The same is when I try to replace foreign towns with special characters in the name of a town (Swedish town, German town, etc.)

Am I doing something wrong???

Comment: does the field columnName contains more data? or it should only hold the word "house"?

Comment: Are you executing this query directly on the server (via command line) or via an external tool? Is it run via code (say PHP for example)? Please ensure that you send the correct character to MySQL, I'm quite sure that's where the problem lies. Another possibility would be related to your table's collation.

Comment: I'm executing it via phpMyAdmin on the server itself. If I try to replace the symbol Å only, it get replaced. But if i try something like this  
UPDATE myTable SET columnName = (replace(columnName, 'Å ', 'SomeThing'))
I get the message: 0 rows affected. That's why I said that the problem is in the 'empty space'

Comment: Table collation is utf8, utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: would this work for you?: `UPDATE myTable SET columnName = TRIM(replace(columnName,'Å',''))`

Comment: If the replacement of the symbol on its own is working but not with the TRIM this would mean that the "empty space" you are seeing isn't really an empty space! otherwise TRIM should have taken care of it!

Comment: Hm, good point because after conversion of the special character only, I still cannot replace the word. Bobince has probably answered what it is. Now, I still have the problem of replacing it non-manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Å house
```

Is likely to actually be:

```
Å house
```

That is, with a U+00A0 Non Break Space character and not a normal space. Of course normally you cannot see the difference, but a string replace can and won't touch it.

This was probably originally just a single non-breaking-space character, that has been mangled through a classic UTF-8-read-as-ISO-8859-1 encoding screw-up. Other non-ASCII characters in your database are likely to have been similarly messed up.

Comment: I don't see the difference. Sorry

Comment: @askmo - what @bobince mean, one is iso-8859-*, another one is UTF-8. If you do not understand, you should do some research on google

Comment: I do understand the encoding, but I do not understand how (if possible at all) to replace characters in such mess-up?

Comment: If you've got columns in your database full of data in the wrong encoding, you'll want to fix that before you can proceed to replace away unwanted characters like U+00A0. This can be done using `ALTER TABLE` on the columns concerned (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html#id2965778 in particular the “warning” section that outlines the change-to-blob-change-to-text dance), or, if the entire database is affected, by dumping to .sql file, loading and saving with a different encoding, then re-importing.